# Simplified summation formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose I have the following recursive formula:

$$A(n)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}+2(n-k)(-1)^{n-k-1}}{2}A(k)$$
Then I can combine the negatives to get
$$A(n)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}-2(n-k)(-1)^{n-k}}{2}A(k)$$
$$A(n)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+[1-2(n-k)](-1)^{n-k}}{2}A(k)$$
Taking care of the negative out front gives me
$$A(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{-1-[1-2(n-k)](-1)^{n-k}}{2}A(k)$$
$$A(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}[2(n-k)-1]-1}{2}A(k)$$
It's better, but is there anything else I can do for simplification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the
constant and $k$ terms
like this:

$\begin{array}\\
A(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}[2(n-k)-1]-1}{2}A(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}(n-k)A(k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}+1}{2}A(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}kA(n-k)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}+1}{2}A(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}kA(n-k)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}A(n-2k)\\
\end{array}
$

That last simplification is due to
$(-1)^{k}+1 = 2$ for even $k$
and $0$ for odd $k$.

As to whether or not this is a simplification
is up to you.